# Higher derivatives of Zeta function for $s>1$?

Tags: integration, derivatives, special-functions, riemann-zeta

I'm searching for integral expressions for $\zeta^{(n)} (s)$ for $n \geq 1$ and general $s$.

I have found two useful papers [1](https://www.jstor.org/stable/2007806) and [2](https://arxiv.org/ftp/arxiv/papers/1506/1506.07386.pdf) from which I was able to obtain the following two cases which seem to work great numerically:

$$1) \qquad \Re (s)<0$$

Denote $$s_1=1-s$$

Then we have:

> $$(-1)^n \zeta^{(n)} (s)= \\ = \frac{1}{(2 \pi  i)^{s_1} } \int_0^{\infty } \frac{t^{s_1-1} \left((-1)^{s_1} \left(\log  t-\log (2 \pi )+\frac{\pi  i}{2}\right)^n+\left(\log t-\log (2 \pi )-\frac{\pi  i}{2}\right)^n\right)}{e^t-1} \, dt$$

It follows from a more general formula (2) in paper 1.*

---

$$2) \qquad 0 < \Re (s)<1$$

Then we have:

> $$\zeta^{(n)} (s)= \\ = \frac{1}{2 \pi  i} \int_0^{\infty } \left(\frac{1}{2 (u+1)}+\log (u)-\psi (u+1)\right) \left(e^{i \pi  s} \left(\log \left(\frac{1}{u}\right)+i \pi \right)^n- \\ -e^{-i \pi  s} \left(\log \left(\frac{1}{u}\right)-i \pi \right)^n\right) \frac{du}{u^s} $$

Which directly follows from formula (1.7) in paper 2.

---

> **My question is**: can we find a similar explicit expression for $\zeta^{(n)} (s)$ with $\Re (s)>1$?

---

$^*$ For anyone who doesn't have access to paper 1, here's the original formula, valid for all complex $s$:

$$(-1)^n \zeta^{(n)} (1-s) = \sum_{k=0}^n \binom{n}{k} \left(e^{s z} z^{n-k}+e^{s z^*} (z^*)^{n-k} \right) \left( \Gamma(s) \zeta(s) \right)^{(k)}$$

Where $z=-\log (2 \pi) - \frac{\pi i}{2}$.

---

> A side question: what other ways exist to numerically evaluate these derivatives? How does Mathematica do it, in case you know?

Comment: Your question doesn't make sense because any representation of $\zeta(s)$ can be differentiated to obtain a representation of the derivatives. What do you mean with "works great numerically" ? And any [series](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dirichlet_eta_function#Numerical_algorithms) representation can be Abel-summed to yield an integral representation.

Comment: @reuns, I mean an integral of a simple closed form function. Usual representations of zeta don't easily lead to a closed form $n$-th derivative. "Works great numerically" means that numerical evaluation of the integral gives at least 20 correct digits in 0.2 seconds in Mathematica. Thank you for your interest

Comment: In fact, both provided examples give a very good clarification of the answer I would like for $s>1$, because they essentially have a very similar dependence on $n$

Comment: Your comment doesn't make sense because there are some $x^s$ in every representation of $\zeta(s)$ which it suffices to differentiate : $(\log x)^k x^s$ to obtain a representation for $\zeta^{(k)}(s)$.

Comment: @reuns, great, please post any such integral that converges for $n>1$ and $s>1$, and gives correct numerical values for the derivatives, and I will accept your answer.

Comment: I already said there is no reason for asking an integral, the series representations are good too. Show where you are stuck at because really to obtain representations for $\zeta^{(k)}(s)$ there is no trick or trap.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finally found a suitable integral expression valid for all $s \neq 1$:

$$\zeta (s)={\frac {1}{s-1}}+{\frac {1}{2}}+2\!\int _{0}^{\infty }\!\!\!{\frac {\sin(s\arctan t)}{\left(1+t^{2}\right)^{\frac {s}{2}}\left(e^{2\pi t}-1\right)}}\,\mathrm {d} t$$

Modifying it a little, I was able to obtain the following expression for the derivative, which seems to work better numerically than all the previous ones.

For $ n \geq 1$ and $s \neq 1$:

> $$\zeta^{(n)}(s)=\frac{(-1)^n n!}{(s-1)^{n+1}}- \\ -i \int_0^{\infty } \frac{dt}{e^{2 \pi  t}-1} \left(\frac{(1+i t)^s}{\left(1+t^2\right)^s} \log ^n\left(\frac{1+i t}{1+t^2}\right)-\frac{(1-i t)^s }{\left(1+t^2\right)^s}\log ^n\left(\frac{1-i t}{1+t^2}\right) \right)$$

Numerical check:

[image]

---

To answer some confusion in the comments, I didn't know about such a nice integral when asking the question. Usual integral representations of Zeta contain Gamma function as well, and so the derivatives have very messy expressions. Not to mention, the integrals are not suitable for numerical evaluation for some parameters, while this one works like a charm.